Java in Anylogic
Can we edit the java code once the model is built in Anylogic?
I am trying to edit the java code, but it's not letting me do that. Are there any suggestions for this? I tried to copy and paste the code in new model but once I build it and if it has errors then I can't edit it.

PS: Only use the anylogic tag, else other SOF users get confused

You do not edit the raw code AnyLogic writes in the background, and there is zero need for that.
What you can do anytime is to create a Java class within AnyLogic (File -> New -> Java class) and use all Java perks that come with it, within your model. See https://anylogic.help/advanced/code/resources-index.html
(advanced modelers do this all the time)
